# how can I get my user_id when I am redirect to a callback url?

Tags: node.js

I use shopify api and they have a auth0 process for login/identity.

I have 2 routes:

```
/auth
and
/auth/callback
```

Code:

```
app.get('/auth', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  // here I have access to user_id
  const { user_id } = req.params;
  try {
    const CheckAccessAndIsCompletedZero = await ShopifyCheckBillShopExists('e8a0d534-4e21-4e9e-a11e-1466f6e8c639');
    
    if(CheckAccessAndIsCompletedZero.completed === 0) {
      // The library will automatically redirect the user
      await shopify.auth.begin({
        shop: shopify.utils.sanitizeShop(req.query.shop, true),
        callbackPath: '/auth/callback',
        isOnline: false,
        rawRequest: req,
        rawResponse: res,
      });
    } else {
      res.json({
        message: 'You dont have access to this process.',
        process: false
      });
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    Sentry.captureException(e);
  }
});
```

Auth/Callback
How can I access now my user_id ? I dont visit the site it is a callback url so I dont have controll about the url parameters or

```
app.get('/auth/callback', async (req: any, res: any) => {
 // 
  try {
  // The library will automatically redirect the user
  const callback = await shopify.auth.callback({
    rawRequest: req,
    rawResponse: res,
  });

  const response = await shopify.webhooks.register({
    session: callback.session,
  });

...
```

I hope you understand me and solve my issue how can I get the user_id in auth/callback